# Consuming a web service with http request response in .NET?

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, soap, httprequest

I need to create xml message and send it to the web service. Then I should handle the response by looking at the response xml that is coming from service. I have used WCF before but I should do it with old style.

Where should I start ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to do it the hard way?

Comment: Thats what my boss want me to do as a junior developer.

Comment: Your boss definitely doesn't want you to call the service through doing all the stuff around HttpWebRequest manually. And if he wants, he is ... By the old way he most probably means ASMX client = Add Web Reference.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka. Actually they have been done many project by that way. Adding web reference is also an restriction. They are doing all parsing process manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use WCF / ASMX clients you should start by learning [HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/) and SOAP ([1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/), [1.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part0/)) to understand needed HTTP headers for POST requests and message construction and reading + [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx). Doing it this way doesn't make sense - stick with WCF or [ASMX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h0yh8f9.aspx) (that is actually the old way).

Answer (score 2):

Here's some basic C# code that does what you want, where url is the URL of the web service you're calling, action is the soap action of the service and envelope is a string containing the soap envelope for the request:

```
WebRequest request = CreateHttpRequestFromSoapEnvelope(url, action, envelope);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

private WebRequest CreateHttpRequestFromSoapEnvelope(string url, string action, string envelope)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "text/xml";
    request.Headers.Add(action);
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

    ApplyProxyIfRequired(request);

    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
            builder.Append(envelope);
            string message = builder.ToString();
            streamWriter.Write(message);
        }
    }

    return request;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the web service. Visual Studio will create classes for you so that you don't need to create the XML request and parse the XML response yourself.
Check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx(v=VS.90).aspx